# Laravel extending class

Tags: php, namespaces, extend, laravel, laravel-3

Are there any other steps required to extend a class in Laravel 3?

I created `application/libraries/response.php`:

```
class Response extends Laravel\Response {

    public static function json($data, $status = 200, $headers = array(), $json_options = 0)
    {
        $headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json; charset=utf-8';

        if(isset($data['error']))
        {
            $status = 400;
        }

        dd($data);

        return new static(json_encode($data, $json_options), $status, $headers);
    }

    public static function my_test()
    {
        return var_dump('expression');
    }

}
```

But for some reason, neither the `my_test()` function, or the modified `json()` function works.

In my controller, I do the following:

```
Response::my_test();
// or
$response['error']['type']    = 'existing_user';
Response::json($response);
```

And none work, what am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should add a name space first - like this:

file: `application/libraries/extended/response.php`

```
<?php namespace Extended;

class Response extends \Laravel\Response {

  public static function json($data, $status = 200, $headers = array(), $json_options = 0)
  {
    $headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json; charset=utf-8';

    if(isset($data['error']))
    {
        $status = 400;
    }

    dd($data);

    return new static(json_encode($data, $json_options), $status, $headers);
  }

  public static function my_test()
  {
    return var_dump('expression');
  }
}
```

Then inside config/application.php you need to change the alias

```
 'Response'     => 'Extended\\Response',
```

Then in start.php

```
Autoloader::map(array(
    'Extended\\Response' => APP_PATH.'libraries/extended/response.php',
));
```

Comment: The output returns: `Class 'Extended\Response' not found`

Comment: Sorry - put the file in /application/libraries/extended/response.php

Comment: Still.. `Class 'Extended\Laravel\Response' not found`

Comment: i made an edit to my post to include an autoloader - try that

Comment: Ok, thank you very much. But is there no other way? I mean, in CodeIgniter is so easy, but in Laravel you have to go trough all this just to extend a class?

Comment: Updated the answer, you need to extends `\Laravel\Response` in this case. Yes it might be simple in CodeIgniter but there a limitation to it as well, feel free to learn the pro and con of using Namespace.

Comment: @w0rldart - I've made another edit based upon crynobone's suggestion - does that work?

Comment: I will try it on monday and let you know :)

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the proper way to extend a library would be the following:

1. Create `response.php` in `application/libraries/`
2. Inside it, extend the class the following way: `class Response extends \Laravel\Response`
3. Comment `'Response' => 'Laravel\\Response'` in `application/config/application.php`

Tested and it works. That's how I do it now