# Laravel 4: Generate HTML Table Like CodeIgniter

Tags: php, laravel-4

So in CodeIgniter, there was a cool feature of creating an HTML table just by passing it an array and it handles the header, etc. Is there ANYTHING out there for Laravel, has anybody been able to use the CI version in Laravel? just asking around

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is nothing like this in `Laravel` AFAIK but you may create your own, something like (an idea only) this (a `php` class, not only for `Laravel`)

```
class Table {

    protected $table = null;
    protected $header = null;
    protected $attr = null;
    protected $data = null;

    public function __construct($data = null, $attr = null, $header = null)
    {
        if(is_null($data)) return;
        $this->data = $data;
        $this->attr = $attr;
        if(is_array($header)) {
            $this->header = $header;
        }
        else {
            if(count($this->data) && $this->is_assoc($this->data[0]) || is_object($this->data[0])) {
                $headerKeys = is_object($this->data[0]) ? array_keys((array)$this->data[0]) : array_keys($this->data[0]);
                $this->header = array();
                foreach ($headerKeys as $value) {
                    $this->header[] = $value;
                }
            }
        }
        return $this;
    }

    public function build()
    {
        $atts = '';
        if(!is_null($this->attr)) {
            foreach ($this->attr as $key => $value) {
                $atts .= $key . ' = "' . $value . '" ';
            }
        }
        $table = '<table ' . $atts . ' >';

        if(!is_null($this->header)) {
            $table .= '<thead><tr>';
            foreach ($this->header as $value) {
                $table .= '<th>' . ucfirst($value) . '</th>';
            }
            $table .= '</thead></tr>';
        }

        $table .= '<tbody>';
        foreach ($this->data as $value) {
            $table .= $this->createRow($value);
        }
        $table .= '</tbody>';
        $table .= '</table>';
        return $this->table = $table;
    }

    protected function createRow($array = null)
    {
        if(is_null($array)) return false;
            $row = '<tr>';
            foreach ($array as $value) {
                $row .= '<td>' . $value . '</td>';
            }
            $row .= '</tr>';
            return $row;
    }

    protected function is_assoc($array){
        return is_array($array) && array_diff_key($array, array_keys(array_keys($array)));
    }
}
```

Now, you can use it as given below ([**<strike>An Example Here.</strike>**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/dnJXru))

```
$data = array(
    array('name' => 'Heera', 'age'=>'35', 'address' =>'Masimpur', 'phone'=>'123456'),
    array('name' => 'Usman', 'age'=>'28', 'address' =>'Kamal Gor', 'phone'=>'654321')
);
$attr = array('class'=>'tbl someClass', 'id'=>'myTbl', 'style'=>'width:400px;color:red', 'border'=>'1');
$t = new Table($data, $attr);
echo $t->build();
```

Or, set an header using third argument, like

```
$t = new Table($data, $attr, array('Known As', 'Years', 'Location', 'Contact'));
```

This is just an idea and could be better. Now just integrate this class with `Laravel` using `Laravel`'s rule. You may extend `Html` class or use as an individual class by registering it as a service. Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14629083/laravel-extending-class/14629223#14629223) for extending a class in `laravel`.

Comment: So I took your class (which works awesome by the way) and added the ability to add an optional row css class to the table (which is useful for some of the bootstrap row classes

Comment: Thanks for this jumpstart! hope you can also add edits to this from time to time bro because people stumble upon this every once in a while even years from now :)

Comment: @Gokigooooks Gald to know it was helpful. You are welcome :-)

Answer (score 2):

Try [nayjest/grids](https://github.com/Nayjest/Grids) Laravel package.

Comment: hi! I really like the functionalities your package brings to the table but the syntax and flow is too difficult for me to get into. PLEASE do a tutorial video or article :D

Comment: What is too complicated about it? The readme.md explains exactly how to use it

Answer (score 0):

You could take the script drupal uses and convert it to laravel: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21includes%21theme.inc/function/theme_table/8

Doing a quick look at it, you would just need to replace a couple of functions:

- Attributes()... I think laravel has something like this you could use.  Drupal 8 is using something from symfony2 I think... laravel might be using the same thing.
- _theme_table_cell(), tablesort_header(), etc... These type of functions have drupal_render() in them... you don't want to try and port that over... so you probably just delete that from the functions (untested) as it doesn't make sense in the context of laravel .

This would make for a very nice implementation of what your looking for.

EDIT:  I also just ran into this: http://kohana.keyframesandcode.com/docs/modules/table/  I've not tested it but it was referenced here: http://forumsarchive.laravel.io/viewtopic.php?id=2178