# Read data from array into an html table

Tags: php, html, arrays, html-table

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [code] => ID 6401
                    [name] => Joseph

                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [code] => ID 6597
                    [name] => Peter
                )

        )
```

I Want print HTML Table like :

Code | Name

ID 6401 | Joseph
ID 6597 | Peter

Total : 2 Person

Comment: [This may help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19672397/laravel-4-generate-html-table-like-codeigniter/19675545#19675545).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try by foreach and assign operator += will be help.

```
<?php
$user = array(
array(
    array(
    "code" => "ID 6401",
    "name" => "Joseph"
    )
),
array(
      array(
    "code" => "ID 6597",
    "name" => "Peter"
    )
));

 ?>
<table>
<thead><th>Code</th><th>Name</th></thead>
<tbody>
<?php 
$count = 0;
foreach ($user as $v){
  echo "<tr><td>".$v[0]['code']."</td><td>".$v[0]['name']."</td></tr>";
  $count += 1;  
}
  echo "<tr><td>Total:</td><td>".$count."</td></tr>";
?>
</tbody>
```

Comment: This is not actually an answer to the question because you have changed the shape of the array and the questioner may not be able to do that or may not want to do that. I admit your array is much more sensible, but its not as per the question

Comment: <?php
$user = array(
    array(
       "code" => "ID 6401",
       "name" => "Joseph"
        ),
    array(
       "code" => "ID 6597",
       "name" => "Peter"
       )
 );
 ?>
<table>
<thead><th>Code</th><th>Name</th></thead>
<tbody>
<?php 
$count = 0;
foreach ($user as $v){
  echo "<tr><td>".$v['code']."</td><td>".$v['name']."</td></tr>";
  $count += 1;  
}
  echo "<tr><td>Total:</td><td>".$count."</td></tr>";
?>
</tbody> it's work before update

Comment: I've changed it as your question array type !

Answer (score 2):

Use this one :

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Code</th><th>Name</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
<?php
    foreach($users as $u){
        echo "<tr><td>". $u[0]['code'] ."</td><td>". $u[0]['name'] ."</td></tr>";
    };
    echo "<tr><td>Total :</td><td>".count($users)."</td></tr>";
?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I have changed the index name as $u[0]['name'] chk revision

Comment: @devpro , ooopss i missed that. Thanks